# A special subgroup of $S_{10}$ generated by four involutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Is there an easy way to describe the subgroup of $S_{10}$ generated by the four involutions:
\begin{align*}
 & (4 ~ 7)(5 ~ 8)(6 ~ 9) \\
 & (2 ~ 7)(3 ~ 8)(6 ~ 10) \\
 & (1 ~ 7)(3 ~ 9)(5 ~ 10) \\
 & (1 ~ 8)(2 ~ 9)(4 ~ 10) 
\end{align*}
I mean is it isomorphic to some known group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group is isomorphic to $S_5$, the permutation representation is that on the cosets of the intransitive subgroup $S_2\times S_3$ with orbits of length 2 and 3.

This was done using GAP in the following way:
Construct the group, verify that it is transitive on the 10 points moved, and identify it in the list (using a prior classification) of transitive groups of degree 10. (Probably
http://oeis.org/A002106
is the easiest linked reference list for these classifications)

```
gap> g:=Group((4,7)(5,8)(6,9),(2,7)(3,8)(6,10),(1,7)(3,9)(5,10),
> (1,8)(2,9)(4,10));;
gap> IsTransitive(g,[1..10]);
true
gap> TransitiveIdentification(g);
13
```

If we fetch the associated group from the library we se that it is an action of $S_5$. (The names are explained in the paper by Conway, McKay and myself that is listed under the above link)

```
gap> TransitiveGroup(10,13);
S_5(10d)
```

Lets try to recreate this permutation group. It must be the action of $S_5$ on the cosets of a subgroup of order 12, find all these subgroups:

```
gap> h:=SymmetricGroup(5);                                                   
Sym( [ 1 .. 5 ] )
gap> u:=List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(h),Representative);;
gap> u:=Filtered(u,x->Size(x)=12);
[ Group([ (3,4,5), (2,4)(3,5) ]), Group([ (3,4,5), (4,5), (1,2)(4,5) ]) ]
```

Now look at the type of the action on the cosets of both subgroups. We find that it gives two different types and one of them is the ``correct'' subgroup for our purposes.

```
gap> List(u,x->TransitiveIdentification(Image(FactorCosetAction(h,x))));
[ 12, 13 ]
gap> v:=u[2];
Group([ (3,4,5), (4,5), (1,2)(4,5) ])
gap> Orbits(v,MovedPoints(h));
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4, 5 ] ]
```

Since the subgroup has two orbits of length 2 and 3 it cannot be other than $S_2\times S_3$.

Comment: What you mean by your remark about the permutation representation, I see that $S_2 \times S_3$ has $10$ cosets in $S_5$, but what has this to do with the above generated subgroup of $S_{10}$?

Comment: Stefan, I guess that if you find a suitable numbering of those 10 cosets, then some set of four generating transpositions of $S_5$ will permute those cosets according to the given recipe. There may be a general method for figuring things like this out, but I'm too ignorant.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your comment, maybe Mr Hulpke adds a few more details for us...

Comment: @Stefan  If you take the permutation action on this subgroup of index 10 you get (for a suitable numbering of the cosets) the permutation representation on 10 points used in the example. (I found this by identifying the group in the library of transitive groups in GAP which does such identification up to point renumbering.)

Comment: I installed GAP on my system now. Would be great if you can post your code!? Might be a simple task, but I just started using GAP.

Comment: @Stefan   I put the commands used in the answer.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that there is a command $\mathtt{StructureDescription}$ which I often use as a first attempt at identifying a group. In this case it returns "S5", which is probably what you wanted to know. It is of limited use for larger groups with more complicated structure, but still useful for providing a rough idea of what the group looks like. And you need to be aware that it is possible for two non-isomorphic groups tho have the same structure description.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks for the useful hint! But let me ask, what you mean by non-isomorphic? Do you mean isomorphic as groups, but not permutation isomorphic, i.e. there is no map $\lambda : \Omega \to \Omega'$ between the points such that $\lambda(\alpha^x) = \lambda(\alpha)^{\psi(x)}$, where $\psi : G \to G'$ denotes a isomorphism between the groups? (Notation from Dixon & Mortimer: Permutation Groups)

Comment: @Stefan  `StructureDescription` may return the same structure for two group that are not (abstractly) isomorphic. It is not an isomorphism invariant. Also it can become very slow its the groups get larger.

Comment: @Stefan: no, just non-isomorphic. See http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.12. In particular, this will be the case if a semidirect product could be formed in more than one way: `StructureDescription` will just tell you that this is a semidirect product of these two groups, but will not tell which exactly.